# Authenticate email/password using firebase for android

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, firebase-authentication, user-registration

i have a very basic question to ask. I am new to android app development. I was strictly following the tutorial instructions from a source. But when it came to storing user data , my tutor was using parse.com . but parse.com will shutdown next year, so that option is closed. so i decided to use firebase instead, now i installed all the packages required. **I want to add email/password authentication on firebase for the signup page in my app. please provide me with the code that  i should add and please also specify where it should be placed(eg. under oncreate)
and also the things i should initialise**

Thanks!

Comment: Check out the official docs on [Authenticate with Firebase using Password-Based Accounts on Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/password-auth).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is my code from LoginActivity class, this includes a login with Google Account , see more in https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

private EditText txtEmail;
private EditText txtPass;

private Button btnLogin;
private Button btnRegister;

private ProgressDialog mProgress;

//firebase
private FirebaseAuth firAuth;

private DatabaseReference firDatabaseUsers;

//gogle sign in
private SignInButton mGoogleBtn;
private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 1;
private static final String TAG = "LoginActivity";
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    firAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();



    firDatabaseUsers = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
    firDatabaseUsers.keepSynced(true);

    txtEmail =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.logintxtEmail);
    txtPass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.logintxtPass);

    btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginbtnEnter);
    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(this);

    mGoogleBtn = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.googlebtn);
    mGoogleBtn.setOnClickListener(this);


    mProgress = new ProgressDialog(this);

    // ---------- GOOGLE SIGN IN ------------

    // Configure Google Sign In
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
            .requestEmail()
            .build();

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this, new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

                }
            })
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();

}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if(view.getId() == R.id.loginbtnEnter) {

        checkLogin();
    }
    else if(view.getId() == R.id.googlebtn) {

        signInGoogle();
    }
}

private void signInGoogle() {
    Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);


        mProgress.setMessage("Iniciando sesión...");
        mProgress.show();
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
            GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();
            firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
        } else {
            // Google Sign In failed, update UI appropriately
            // ...

            mProgress.dismiss();

        }
    }
}

private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
    Log.d(TAG, "firebaseAuthWithGoogle:" + acct.getId());

    AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
    firAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());

                    // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                    // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                    // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential", task.getException());
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Autenticación Fallida.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else {
                        mProgress.dismiss();
                        checkUserExist();

                    }
                    // ...


                }
            });
}


private void checkLogin () {

    String _email = txtEmail.getText().toString().trim();
    String _pass = txtPass.getText().toString().trim();

    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(_email) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(_pass)) {

        mProgress.setMessage("Comprobando");
        mProgress.show();

        firAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(_email, _pass).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                if(task.isSuccessful() ) {

                    mProgress.dismiss();

                    checkUserExist();

                }
                else {

                    mProgress.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Error al ingresar", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });


    }
}

private void checkUserExist () {

    if(firAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {

        final String _user_id = firAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

        firDatabaseUsers.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                if (dataSnapshot.hasChild(_user_id)) {

                    Intent iSetup = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    iSetup.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

                    startActivity(iSetup);

                } else {

                    Intent iSetup = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    iSetup.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

                    startActivity(iSetup);

                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

}
```

}

To register an user yo need to run this code

```
    final String _name = txtName.getText().toString().trim();
    String _email = txtEmail.getText().toString().trim();
    String _pass = txtPass.getText().toString().trim();

    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(_name) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(_email) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(_pass) ) {

        mProgress.setMessage("Registrando ...");
        mProgress.show();

        firAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(_email, _pass).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                if(task.isSuccessful()) {

                   //the user has been registered

                }
            }
        });
```

hope it helps